# Is there a way to create a new user account within Android?

Tags: android

I'd like to be able to create a special user account that would exist on an android device.  Since it is based on the Linux kernel, I was hoping there was a way to create a group account and then create a user account.  Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to be able to create a
>   special user account that would exist
>   on an android device.

To do...what?

> I was hoping there was a way to create
>   a group account and then create a user
>   account

No, you do not have control over this, except on a rooted device.

Comment: >>To do...what?
To run an app that needs more control over the system 

>>No, you do not have control over this, except on a rooted device.
So, on a rooted device, can I explicitly create a named user and group ?  Or will I just have SuperUser access on the main (and only) user?

Comment: "To run an app that needs more control over the system" For your own phone, you may be able to root it. For more widespread use, your "app that needs more control" would have to be part of the firmware. "So, on a rooted device, can I explicitly create a named user and group ? Or will I just have SuperUser access on the main (and only) user?" AFAIK, you can get to root shells and do what you want. However, I don't root my devices, so I do not have practical hands-on experience.

Comment: Could I then use something like busybox shell to do an adduser ?

Comment: That would be a question best answered by whoever's instructions you use to root whatever device you have. However, I understand that busybox has been ported to run on Android ARM devices.